# Refresh page after alert OK

Tags: javascript, html, safari, alert, enter

I need that when the user press the ENTER key the form doesn't submit. And I already make that but when the alert comes and the user accepts, the form submits. It only happens with Safari users.

My code! and thanks...

```
<script>
    function alerta(e)
    {               
        var unicode
        if (e.charCode)
        {unicode=e.charCode;}
        else
        {unicode=e.keyCode;}

        if (unicode == 13){
            alert("message alert");
            window.location.reload();
        }           
    }
</script>

<form method="post" action="verifi.php" onkeypress="alerta(event)">
 ...
</form>
```

Comment: Call `e.preventDefault()` to prevent form submission.

Comment: But I need that the form submit, but not when the users in Safari accepts in the alert.

PS: I'm starting with javascript, don't have too much experience.

Comment: Do that in the `if` block.

Comment: You should use `confirm()` if you need the user to make a choice, not `alert()`.

Comment: The alert it's just for a notification to the user. Like 'your message has been send" but when the user press ok the form submit and only happens with Safari.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Do you want the form to submit, or do you want to prevent the form from submitting? If you want the form to submit, why are you calling `reload()`? That reloads the page, which stops all scripts.

Comment: , you're calling a function on every key press which will be bad for system resources, use onsubmit instead of onkeypress.

Comment: I want that the form submit but not when the users press ENTER key without accept terms and conditions. I already made that but in Safari when the user press ENTER, the alert comes out you press OK and the form submit. That is what I want to prevent.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `alert("message alert");` use `window.confirm("message alert");`
I am using chrome.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).keypress(function(event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
      event.preventDefault();
      window.confirm("Are you sure you want to submit this form?");
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });
</script>

<form method="post" action="verifi.php">
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: window.confirm(); is better than window.alert(); in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Add `return false;` to the end of your javascript function. This will prevent the form from submission.

Comment: I want that the form submit but not when the users press ENTER key without accept terms and conditions. I already made that but in Safari when the user press ENTER, the alert comes out you press OK and the form submit. That is what I want to prevent.